# Group by date but not include time - Oracle SQl

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, grouping

I'm trying to use listagg to group categories by date, but the field is date-time. Categories are appearing on separate lines. Is it possible to group by date only? I've tried CAST as well as DATE in the group by, but it's still not working. Here's the base query:

```
select ACCOUNT,
       ID,
       NAME,
       TERM,
       listagg(CATEGORY, ', ') within group (order by CATEGORY) as cat_by_date,
       trunc(TRANSACTION_DATE) short_date   

  from TABLE
 where term= '2022'
       and CATEGORY in ('T', 'H', 'P')

 group by
       ACCOUNT_UID,
       ID,
       NAME,
       TERM,
       TRANSACTION_DATE
       
 order by 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TRUNC in the GROUP BY as well

```
...
 group by
       ACCOUNT_UID,
       ID,
       NAME,
       TERM,
       TRUNC(TRANSACTION_DATE)
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew I was missing something obvious.